# C relocation 0 has invalid symbol index

Tags: c

First of all, I am sorry for possible nonsense somewhere in my code, I am more then a beginner.. I am trying to compile this code with

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

//initial conditions
//#define rs0 2.064594102e11
//#define re0 5.064594102e16
//#define vs0 2.929599982
//#define ve0 29295.99982
#define ms 1.9891e30
#define me 5.9736e24
#define a 149598261e3
#define e 0.0167112303531389
#define G 6.67428e-11
#define Tday 86164.1
//#define Tyear 31552844.28
#define I1 8.008e37
#define I3 8.034e37
#define Theta0 24.45




typedef void (*vector_function)(double* y, double t, double* f);

void integrator(vector_function f, int n, double* y,
            double t, double dt, double* yn)
{
double k1[n],k2[n],k3[n],k4[n],ytmp[n];
double deriv[n]; // note that dynamic arrays are
// a C99 feature -- check your compiler flags
f(y, t, deriv);
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
    k1[i] = deriv[i] * dt;
    ytmp[i]=y[i]+0.5*dt*deriv[i];
    //diff[i]=deriv[i];
}
f(ytmp,t+0.5*dt,deriv);
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    k2[i]=dt*deriv[i];
    ytmp[i]=y[i]+0.5*dt*deriv[i];
}
f(ytmp,t+0.5*dt,deriv);
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    k3[i]=dt*deriv[i];
    ytmp[i]=y[i]+dt*deriv[i];
}
f(ytmp,t+dt,deriv);
for(int i=0;i<n;++i) k4[i]=dt*deriv[i];

for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    yn[i]=y[i]+(k1[i]+2*k2[i]+2*k3[i]+k4[i])/6;
}
for (int i=0; i<12; ++i)
{
 y[i] = yn[i];
}
}


void F(double *y, double t, double* f)
{
double re0 = (a*(1+e)*ms)/(me+ms);
double rs0 = (-me*re0)/ms;
double kE = (G*ms*me/a)*(-0.5 + (1/(1+e)));
double ve0 = sqrt((2*kE)/(me*(1+(me/ms))));
double vs0 = -me*ve0/ms;
double Tyear = (2*3.141592*pow(a, 2/3))/sqrt(G*(ms+me));

double d[3] = {y[0]-y[6], y[1]-y[7], y[5]-y[8]};
double dcube = pow((y[0]-y[6])*(y[0]-y[6])+(y[1]-y[7])*(y[1]-y[7])+(y[5]-y[8])* (y[5]-y[8]), 3);


for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
{
//Force Earth
f[i] = G*ms*d[i]/dcube;

//Velocity Earth
f[3+i] = y[3+i];

//Force Sun
f[6+i] = -G*me*d[i]/dcube;

//Velocity Sun
f[9+i] = y[9+i];
}



int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int Tmax, m;
    //printf("Please input number of the years\n");
    //scanf("%i",&y);
    Tmax = Tyear;
    printf("please input the number of steps \n");
    scanf("%d",&m);

//        y[11] = {re0, 0, 0, 0, ve0, 0, rs0, 0, 0, 0, vs0, 0};
    double y[11], yn[11];
    //,sum[2];

    y[0]=re0;
    y[1]=0;
    y[2]=0;
    y[3]=0;
    y[4]=ve0;
    y[5]=0;
    y[6]=rs0;
    y[7]=0;
    y[8]=0;
    y[9]=0;
    y[10]=vs0;
    y[11]=0;


    double t=0;
    double dt=( Tmax-t )/m;
    // the runge-kuta integrator starts from here
    for (int k=0; k<m;k++)
    {
        t=t+dt;
        integrator(F, 12,  y, t, dt, yn);
        printf("%e %e %e %e\n", t, y[0], y[1], y[2]);
        for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) y[i] = yn[i];
    }
    printf("the intigrated components of the radius-vector and the velosity of the Earth are:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<6; ++i)
    {
     printf("%lf", yn[i]);
    }

    printf("the intigrated components of the radius-vector and the velosity of the Sun are:\n");
    for (int i=6; i<12; ++i)
    {
     printf("%lf", yn[i]);
    }

   /* printf("the intigrated vr is %lf\n",yn[1]);
    printf("the intigrated theta is %lf\n",yn[2]);*/
    //fprintf(f,"%lf/t%lf/n",y[0],y[2]);
    //fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
}
```

And I compile it with:

```
Main: main.c
    gcc -c main.c -o main -std=c99 -lm
```

It does not create an executive file and I get permission is denied.

A also tried to use the same makefiel without -c.. doesn't work and produce this bunch of errors which are stated in the topic. Help=(

Comment: If you're getting `permission denied`, you may have a `main.o` file that doesn't have write permission.

Answer (score 1):

So, there are at least 2 problems:

1. If you indent your code, you can see that your `F()` function is missing a closing brace.
2. Don't use `-c` in your compilation line.

Answer (score 1):

Nested function is not allowed in C, i.e, you can't define a function inside another one.  You are defining your `main` inside the function

```
void F(double *y, double t, double* f){..}
```

which is wrong.